# Which Spring Cloud AWS version should be used with Spring Boot 3?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-aws

I am trying to make `SqsListener` work but I can't with Spring Boot 3, it simply doesn't receive anything. When I change Spring Boot version back to 2.X everything's work perfectly.
I am using 2.4.2 version of Spring cloud:

```
...
    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Can you please point me to the correct version of spring cloud?
Would I need to use milestone version for that?

Comment: Should be `2022.0.0-RC2`
Take a look at https://start.spring.io

Comment: Spring Cloud AWS is not part of the spring cloud release train. So 2022.0.0 is not the right answer and I'm not sure what is

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't work as version 2.4.2 of spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging relies on `spring.factories` for Spring Boot autoconfiguration, but the support for that has been removed in Spring Boot 3.0.0. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#auto-configuration-files.

You can enable the auto configuration by creating the following file

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports

# content
io.awspring.cloud.autoconfigure.messaging.SqsAutoConfiguration
```

But, it probably won't work anyway as spring-cloud-aws also relies on classes from Spring Messaging that were deprecated and removed in Spring 6 (which is used in Spring Boot 3), specifically `org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver`.

You'll have to wait for Spring Cloud AWS to support Spring Boot 3. They are working on Spring Cloud AWS 3.0.0, but I don't think it has a release date yet. https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It should be noted that since then spring-cloud-aws officially released v3 of their project. For me that fixed issues with receiving SQS messages using Spring Boot 3.

Answer (score 3):

cloud-aws` release here:
https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws

So `spring-cloud-aws` should use `3.0.x` with Spring Boot `3.0.x`

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

[image: Compatibility with Spring Projects]

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work (Spring Boot 3.0.4 and AWS SqsListener).  I cobbled together a bunch of different postings and articles.  I think this is the solution really:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.25</version>
    </dependency>
```

I got really frustrated finding an end to end solution for it so I put this out on GitHub. Hopefully it helps someone else but this seems to move fast in ten different directions at once.

https://github.com/thomashcampbell/SpringBootSQSExample

Comment: Combining this tip with the accepted answer, i.e. adding the auto configuration imports file, ensures that the auto-configuration parameters like AWS region etc. are actually respected. Not sure if that workaround is production-ready by any means, but it's enough for prototypting.

Answer (score 0):

@EnableSqs

add this annotation in the class where you are using @SqsListener in spring boot 3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).