# When will Spring Cloud AWS 3.0.0 be released?

Tags: spring-cloud-aws, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis

**When is the planned release date for Spring Cloud AWS 3.0.0?** I checked https://calendar.spring.io/ and do not see a planned release date published there. We are migrating our microservices to use Spring Boot 3.0.0, Spring Cloud 2022.0.1, and Spring Cloud Stream Binder for Kinesis 3.0.0. All of our testing so far has been successful except for our `@SqsListener` testing. We ran across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74852003/which-spring-cloud-aws-version-should-be-used-with-spring-boot-3/75017985#75017985) stackoverflow post describing the exact problem we are experiencing, and as it's stated there, there isn't a known or published date for Spring Cloud AWS 3.0.0. As projects get migrated to use the very latest Spring project releases, anyone using and testing the `@SqsListener` available with the Spring Cloud AWS 2.4.2 libraries would run into a similar problem I would expect. Also, once Spring Cloud AWS 3.0.0 is available, I would expect that the Spring Cloud Stream Binder for Kinesis would also be updated to use it.

Comment: If the developers aren't publishing a date I don't know why you would think we'd know.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular see the response from a Spring Cloud AWS contributor below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Cloud AWS 3.0 is currently in RC1 and we don't have a release date for GA as we're still collecting feedback.

Feel free to give it a try and let us know if you run into any issues.

Comment: Our current issue is that we can't migrate to Spring Boot 3.0.0, Spring Cloud 2022.0.1, and Spring Cloud Stream Binder for Kinesis 3.0.0 since we use ```@SqsListener``` and Kinesis in our applications. This is because ```@SqsListener``` requires Spring Cloud AWS 3.0 and the Spring Cloud Stream Binder for Kinesis references Spring Cloud AWS 2.4.2. Until Spring Cloud AWS 3.0 is released and Spring Cloud Stream Binder for Kinesis is updated to use it, we will not be able to upgrade. At this point, this appears to be our only blocker.

Comment: I feel your pain. Spring Cloud Stream team will probably not start working on upgrading to Spring Cloud AWS 3.0 before we release GA. Unfortunately we don't have a release date for GA yet. Bear with us that we're a team of volunteers doing this in our spare time :)

Comment: I, as well as many others, appreciate all of the hard work you and many others put into these projects. My point here is simply to outline the dependencies we have between these various projects and attempt to explain why we can't yet migrate to the latest versions of Spring Boot, Spring Cloud, and Spring Cloud Stream Binder for Kinesis. I look forward to the GA release of Spring Cloud AWS 3.0! Thanks, Tomaz!